# Installing E3D v6 extruder electronics on Ultimaker Original+

Tags: electronics, ultimaker-original, e3d-v6

I printed the mechanical parts to mount a E3D v6 on my Ultimaker Original+. But I don't know how to connect my heating cartridge, my thermistor and my 3 fans to the electronic board. Any idea?

Edit: I should have said I'm using the following design: https://www.youmagine.com/designs/e3d-v6-hot-end-mount

My main problem is to connect all 3 fans, as the original design of the UMO+ is only using one.

Comment: Hi, Alexis. Could you please elaborate on what *specific* electronics you have and want to connect? This way, your question can be answered by users who does not know the insides of the Ultimaker Original+.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain exactly what you're asking, but I'll give this a try. If I've misunderstood, please give more details.

It sounds like you're upgrading to the E3D v6. If so, the heater, thermistor, and fans should connect to the same places as the previous ones did. The exception would be if you had thermocouples instead of thermistors before; that's a more complicated change.

If the *connectors* are different, you'll need to get matching connectors from a parts supplier (post a picture if you're having trouble identifying them). Fortunately each of the items you mentioned has 2 wires, and for the heater and thermistor polarity doesn't matter.

For fans, polarity *does* matter, so match up red vs. black, or just try it one way, and if the fan doesn't turn, then swap the wires. Some fans have a third wire, which could be used for measuring the actual rotation speed (see [http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/How_PC_Fans_Work]); but it's not necessary.

Comment: I'm using that design: https://www.youmagine.com/designs/e3d-v6-hot-end-mount and I'm mainly looking to connect the 2 additional fans.

Comment: You should be able to just splice the two fans together (red to red, black to black), and connect that where ever the extruder fan you already had was. There should be plenty of power for 2 small fans. If the picture I found at http://wiki.ultimaker.com/images/El1.5.4-PCB.jpg is  right, I *think* the extruder fan connector is the one all by itself at the lower right.

Comment: Actually, the UMO+ has an UMO2 board: http://www.printme3d.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1010x850/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/o/motherboard.jpg All 3 fans are 12V.